# How to replace div with table

Tags: css

I have a layout that is table-based with three columns but I have to change it with div based 
I have to do it with the styles i.e,

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
FirstName
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
LastName
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table
```

How could I make it simple table div based by applying CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `<table>`.
2. Replace `<tr>...</tr>`-tags with `<div class="Row">...</div>`.
3. Replace `<td>...</td>`-tags with `<div class="Cell">...</div>`.
4. Add CSS:

   `.Cell{
       float: left;
       width: 200px;
   }`